# Set radio button initial value in react native

Tags: react-native, radio-button

I'm trying to set the initial value of my radio buttons in react native, but it is always setting to "No" even though the values are different.

```
...
import RadioForm from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
...

render() {
  ...
  const { CompanyPayFee, AllPropertiesTenantPortal } = this.state.myData;
  const radio_props = [
    {label: 'Yes  ', value: 0 },
    {label: 'No', value: 1 }
  ];
  console.log(CompanyPayFee, AllPropertiesTenantPortal);
  ...

  return (
    ...

  <RadioForm
     radio_props={radio_props}
     initial={CompanyPayFee}
     formHorizontal={true}
     labelHorizontal={true}
     buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
     animation={true}
     buttonSize={15}
     onPress={(text) => this.onChangeSettings(text, 'CompanyPayFee')}
  />

  ...

  <RadioForm
     radio_props={radio_props}
     initial={AllPropertiesTenantPortal}
     formHorizontal={true}
     labelHorizontal={true}
     buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
     animation={true}
     buttonSize={15}
     onPress={(text) => this.onChangeSettings(text, 'AllPropertiesTenantPortal')}
  />

  ...

  );
}
```

The console.log is returning:

```
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
undefined undefined
0 1
0 1
```

However, the

Could it be because the initial value, in the log, is undefined? But it changes to 1 or 0 later.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have ternary operation inside of initialState, your initial state should be something constant either 0 or 1. When you get values back from database that time just update radio_props value and it will get updated on the UI, react does everything for you once it gets the props value.

Comment: I removed the ternary operator and just keep the values from the database (1 or 0), but is still always setting to "No"